# cucumber.api.PendingException: TODO: implement me

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

It does not seem to be getting data
Could you please tell me why that is happening?

> ```
> cucumber.api.PendingException: TODO: implement me
>   at cucumber.runtime.junit.JUnitReporter.addFailure(JUnitReporter.java:150)
>   at cucumber.runtime.junit.JUnitReporter.addFailureOrIgnoreStep(JUnitReporter.java:138)
>   at cucumber.runtime.junit.JUnitReporter.result(JUnitReporter.java:98)
>   at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runStep(Runtime.java:282)
>   at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runStep(StepContainer.java:44)
>   at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runSteps(StepContainer.java:39)
>   at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:44)
>   at cucumber.runtime.junit.ExecutionUnitRunner.run(ExecutionUnitRunner.java:102)
>   at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
>   at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
>   at cucumber.runtime.junit.ExamplesRunner.run(ExamplesRunner.java:59)
>   at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
>   at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
>   at cucumber.runtime.junit.ScenarioOutlineRunner.run(ScenarioOutlineRunner.java:53)
>   at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:63)
>   at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:18)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
>   at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.run(FeatureRunner.java:70)
>   at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:95)
>   at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:38)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
>   at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.run(Cucumber.java:100)
>   at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
>   at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
>   at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
>   at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
>   at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
>   at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
> ```

```
Feature: Test login to y4 web

#Scenario: Login with given account
#
#Given User is already login page
#When Title of login page is Login Y4
#Then User enter username "phanminh@y-4.jp" and User enrer password "test1234"
#Then User click on Login button
#Then User is on Homepage


Scenario Outline: Login with given account

Given User is already login page
When Title of login page is Login Y4
Then User enter username "<username>" and User enter password "<password>"
Then User click on Login button
Then User is on Homepage
Then Click on Home icon
Then Click on Search icon
Then Select user "<user>"
Then Select start date <start_year> <start_month> <start_date>
Then Select end date <end_year> <end_month> <end_date>
Then Click on search
Then Download excel file
Then Validate Download excel file
Then Close the browser


Examples:
    |username|password|user|start_year|start_month|start_date|end_year|end_month|end_date|
    |phanminh@y-4.jp|test1234|Yukinao Ajima|2019|01|01|2019|07|25|
    |chiptest025@gmail.com|12345678|Huu Nguyen|2019|08|01|2019|08|25|
```

```
Feature: report select users y4 web


Scenario: report select users with given account

Given User is already login page
When Title of login page is Login Y4
Then User enter username "phanminh@y-4.jp" and User enrer password "test1234"
Then User click on Login button
Then User is on Homepage
Then Select following users
    |minhphan116@gmail.com.vn|
    |chipbuuu@gmail.com|
    |yukinaoajima@gmail.com|
    |nvhuu.grandm@gmail.com|
    |stb.0201@gmail.com|
Then Click next
Then Select start date
    |2019|01|01|
Then Select end date
    |2019|08|26|
Then Click Search to download
```

```
package stepDefinition;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import cucumber.api.DataTable;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;
import junit.framework.Assert;

public class LoginStepDefinition {

    WebDriver driver;
    String downloadPath = "/Users/DELL/Downloads/";

    @Given("^User is already login page$")
    public void user_already_on_login() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/DELL/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe");

        HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
        chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads", 1);
        chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", System.getProperty(downloadPath));

        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);

        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.get("https://y4.genkimiru.jp/");
    }

    @When("^Title of login page is Login Y(\\d+)$")
    public void title_of_login_page_is_Login_Y(int arg1) throws Throwable {
        String title = driver.getTitle();
        System.out.print(title);
        Assert.assertEquals("Genkimiru & Vital Gain", title);
    }

    @Then("^User enter username \"([^\"]*)\" and User enrer password \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void user_enter_username_and_User_enrer_password(String username, String password) throws Throwable {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        driver.findElement(By.name("data[User][email]")).sendKeys(username);
        driver.findElement(By.name("data[User][password]")).sendKeys(password);
    }

    @Then("^User click on Login button$")
    public void user_click_on_Login_button() throws Throwable {
        WebElement loginBtn = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='submit']"));
        JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", loginBtn);
    }

    @Then("^User is on Homepage$")
    public void user_is_on_Homepage() throws Throwable {
        String homeTitle = driver.findElement(By.className("site_title")).getText();
        Assert.assertEquals("ユーザー管理", homeTitle);
    }

    @Then("^Close the browser$")
    public void close_the_browser() throws Throwable {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        driver.quit();
    }

    @Then("^Click on Home icon$")
    public void click_on_Home_icon() throws Throwable {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        WebElement home = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@id='menu_1']//a"));
        JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", home);
    }

    @Then("^Click on Search icon$")
    public void click_on_Search_icon() throws Throwable {
        WebElement home = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@id='menu_5']//a"));
        JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", home);
    }

    @Then("^Select user \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void select_user(String user) throws Throwable {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        Select users = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("data[Report][customer_id]")));
        System.out.print("" + users.getAllSelectedOptions().size());
        users.selectByVisibleText(user);
    }

    @Then("^Select start date (\\d+) (\\d+) (\\d+)$")
    public void select_start_date(int year, int month, int date) throws Throwable {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        String time = String.format("%d年%02d月%02d日", year, month, date);
        WebElement dateButton = driver.findElement(By.id("ReportFrom"));
        JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", dateButton);

        dateButton.clear();
//        dateButton.click();
        dateButton.sendKeys(Keys.DELETE);
        dateButton.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.COMMAND, "A"), time);
    }

    @Then("^Select end date (\\d+) (\\d+) (\\d+)$")
    public void select_end_date(int year, int month, int date) throws Throwable {
        String time = String.format("%d年%02d月%02d日", year, month, date);
        WebElement dateButton = driver.findElement(By.id("ReportTo"));
        JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", dateButton);

        dateButton.clear();
//        dateButton.click();
        dateButton.sendKeys(Keys.DELETE);
        dateButton.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.COMMAND, "A"), time);
    }

    @Then("^Click on search$")
    public void click_on_search() throws Throwable {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        WebElement search = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-danger pull-right']"));
        JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", search);
    }

    @Then("^Download excel file$")
    public void download_excel_file() throws Throwable {
        WebElement download = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='btn btn-info pull-right']"));
        String downloadURL = download.getAttribute("href");
        driver.navigate().to(downloadURL);
        JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", download);
        String filenameDownload = downloadURL.split("/")[downloadURL.split("/").length - 1];
        System.out.println(filenameDownload);
        // Validate excel file
        boolean found = false;
        long timeout = 20;// 20 seconds
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while (!found && ((System.currentTimeMillis() - now) / 1000) < timeout) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            File folder = new File(downloadPath);
            File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
            for (File listOfFile : listOfFiles) {
                if (listOfFile.isFile()) {
                    String fileName = listOfFile.getName();
                    if (fileName.contains(filenameDownload)) {
                        found = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (!found) {
            Assert.assertTrue(found);
        }
    }

    @Then("^Select following users$")
    public void select_following_users(DataTable arg1) throws Throwable {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        // For automatic transformation, change DataTable to one of
        // List<YourType>, List<List<E>>, List<Map<K,V>> or Map<K,V>.
        // E,K,V must be a scalar (String, Integer, Date, enum etc)
        List<String> users = arg1.asList(String.class);
        WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@id='DataTables_Table_0']//tbody"));
        List<WebElement> rows = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
        for (WebElement element : rows) {
            String text = element.getText().trim();
            for (String user : users) {
                if (text.contains(user)) {
                    JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
                    executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element.findElement(By.tagName("input")));
                }
            }

        }
    }

    @Then("^Click next$")
    public void click_next() {
        WebElement next = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='actionButton']"));
        JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", next);
    }

    @Then("^Select start date$")
    public void select_start_date(DataTable arg1) {
        List<List<String>> data = arg1.raw();
        String time = String.format("%d年%02d月%02d日", Integer.valueOf(data.get(0).get(0)), Integer.valueOf(data.get(0).get(1)), Integer.valueOf(data.get(0).get(2)));
        WebElement dateButton = driver.findElement(By.id("ReportFrom"));
        JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", dateButton);

        new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(dateButton));
        dateButton.clear();
//        dateButton.click();
        dateButton.sendKeys(Keys.DELETE);
        dateButton.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.COMMAND, "A"), time);
    }

    @Then("^Select end date$")
    public void select_end_date(DataTable arg1) {
        List<List<String>> data = arg1.raw();
        String time = String.format("%d年%02d月%02d日", Integer.valueOf(data.get(0).get(0)), Integer.valueOf(data.get(0).get(1)), Integer.valueOf(data.get(0).get(2)));
        WebElement dateButton = driver.findElement(By.id("ReportTo"));
        JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", dateButton);

        new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(dateButton));

        dateButton.clear();
//        dateButton.click();
        dateButton.sendKeys(Keys.DELETE);
        dateButton.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.COMMAND, "A"), time);
    }

    @Then("^Click Search to download$")
    public void click_Search_to_download() {
        WebElement submit = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='submitBtn']"));
        JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", submit);
    }

    @Then("^validate Download excel file$")
    public void validate_Download_excel_file() throws Throwable {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        System.out.print("tao validare roi");
    }
}
```

```
package Runner;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "C:\\Users\\DELL\\Downloads\\cucumber-sample\\Cucumbertest1\\src\\main\\java\\Feature",
        glue= {"stepDefinition"},
        dryRun = false,
        monochrome = true,//display the console output in a proper readable format
        strict=true,//it will check any step is not defined in step definition file
        format = {"pretty", "html:test-out"})//check mapping betwwen feature and def file


public class TestRunner {

}
```

Comment: It seems the method `JUnitReporter.addFailure()` at JUnitReporter.java:150 hasn't been implemented.

Answer (score 3):

This means that your step is not implemented. (Or Cucumber cannot find the step definition for your step).